# How to repair bootcamp after partitioning for triple boot

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, partition

I already had El Capitan and Windows running smoothly. I needed to add a partition so I could triple boot into Ubuntu. OS X and Ubuntu both work perfectly now but my Boot Camp side seems to have gotten screwed up.

I now get the following error when I try and go onto my windows partition: "Recovery. Your PC needs to be repaired. Error code: 0x000000e"

The thing is, on my Mac side, I can still see Boot Camp under devices and I can access my files. Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Last time when I tries to partition my Mac, Bootcamp got messed up, what I did is boot into the Windows 10 installer (CD or USB). You can download an ISO [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), then burn it to an DVD disc or USB drive. Then pass through the language selection screen, when you get to a screen that says Install Now, there should be a button on the bottom left corner saying Repair This Computer (or something like that, I don't have the CD right now). You should get to a screen similar to this, click Advanced options:

[image: Troubleshoot]

Now click on Startup Repair:

[image: Advanced]

Then follow the instruction to fix startup, then you should be able to boot back into Windows 10.

Hope this help.

P.S. This seems like a problem with the MBR when you partition the drive.

If that can't fix Windows 10 startup, you may be having some problems with the Windows partition.